# Matching any Unicode whitespace

Tags: regular-expression, search, whitespace, unicode

I'd like to match in Vim any whitespace character, not only normal space (U+0020) and tab (U+0009) with `\s`, and the other ASCII ones like form feed (U+000C) with `[[:space:]]`, but any Unicode whitespace character, like e.g. NBSP (U+00A0), ENSP (U+2002), "asian space" (U+3000), etc., without listing them all in `[]`.

One would like to match whole [Unicode category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) (`Zs`), but Vim pattern syntax does not seem to support those, unlike eg. Perl (`\p{}`).

Equivalence class matching cannot be used as well. Eg. `[[=a=]]` matches all "aàá", but `[[= =]]` matches only ordinary space character.

Is there an elegant way to do it?

Comment: not possible with vim regular expressions

Comment: What about using perl's capabilities in a vim function, or as a filter?

Answer (score 4):

You asked for elegant, but got no answer... so here's the non-elegant way, listing [all 25 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) defined as whitespace:

```
\(\%u0009\|\%u000A\|\%u000B\|\%u000C\|\%u000D\|\%u0020\|\%u0085\|\%u00A0\|\%u1680\|\%u2000\|\%u2001\|\%u2002\|\%u2003\|\%u2004\|\%u2005\|\%u2006\|\%u2007\|\%u2008\|\%u2009\|\%u200A\|\%u2028\|\%u2029\|\%u202F\|\%u205F\|\%u3000\)
```